# Unescape of special characters < and > in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I am storing in my Oracle SQL database table string field with tag values having '<' and '>'. when I try to to retrieve them for Xmlhttp request the values displayed are '&lt' and '&gt'. How can I prevent this conversion and display '<' and '>' symbols?

I used the following functions that I found but did not work(Also tried using xmlgen but it did not work form me)

```
select UTL_I18N.UNESCAPE_REFERENCE(string_field) from test where id='123'
```

Here the string_field column of test table of type Char has the value `<test><tags>ABC<test><tags>` and I want to display the same value with out < and > being replaced by &lt and &gt.

How is it possible?

Comment: Unable to replicate [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=4a93c0abd07e35cd140f24dc684cbbd3). Please [edit] your question with a [MRE] that includes: DDL statement for your table; DML statement for inserting the sample data into your table; the query you are using to extract the data; and your expected output so that we can replicate the issue.

Comment: Are you positively sure this is happening in the SELECT query? How have you verified that stored values are `<` and `>` if Oracle allegedly encodes then when retrieving then?

Comment: Hi MT0 yes stored values are with < and > this happens in XML conversion in application. Just doing a select query using oracle sql devleoper does not create any issue but in getting converted to xml http request the issue occurs

Comment: "this happens in XML conversion in application" — So, it this a question about Oracle? I'd say that in whatever language and library you're using to generate XML, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: but I noticed DMS_XMLGEN function in oralce sql that I hope could be used to overcome this even thoughh I am not  excatly  sure

Comment: As I said, please give us a [MRE] with the code you are using to generate the data that is producing the issue. If we have to guess what you are doing that doesn't work then you aren't going to get good/relevant answers.